# Ruby on Rails: How to update a record's attributes except one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails app I have an `update` action that `users` can use to update their profile.

The tricky thing I want to achieve is that if a user enters a **new** email address and saves it, that email address won't get saved to the `email` database field straightaway, but rather to a database field called `new_email`. The field `email` should remain untouched (at least until the `user` has confirmed that email address later on).

```
def update
  current_email = @user.email
  new_email = params[:user][:email].downcase.to_s
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])    
    if new_email != current_email
      @user.change_email(current_email, new_email)     
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated. Please confirm your new email by clicking on the link that we've sent you."
    else
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
    end
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

**User model:**

```
def change_email(old_email, new_email)
  self.new_email = new_email.downcase 
  self.email = old_email
  self.send_email_confirmation_link
end
```

The function above *kind of* works but is hard to test and *doesn't feel right*. Is there a smoother way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the user is updating their email address why would they then want to confirm the change? If you want you can create versioning that they can revert later on (there are some gems out there for this, paper_clip, vestal_versions).

Comment: @spullen, it's standard practice to confirm email changes by emailing the new email address. It accounts for typos and all sorts of user error.

Comment: Yes, I am emailing to the `new_email`. The user then has to confirm that email address by clicking on a link.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your form so that you're updating `new_email`, you can just put it all in a simple `after_update` hook.

```
after_update :check_new_email

private
  def check_new_email
    send_email_confirmation_link if new_email_changed?
  end
```

Comment: I thought `after_update` is [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update)? I am on Rails 3.2.13 by the way...

Comment: @Tintin81: it's not deprecated :).

Comment: Ah ok. Is `new_email_changed?` a method that I have to write myself or is it a Rails method?

Comment: nope, that's part of [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: I also wonder how to render a custom flash message when the `user` changes his email address. Normally, this would be done in the controller, right?

Comment: Yeah, that kinda thing does belong in the controller so I don't see any problem with keeping your `if params[:user][:new_email] != @user.email` logic there for your flash messages. With regards to `after_update`, I didn't see that you put a link. What is deprecated is overriding the `after_update` _method_ in the model, as opposed to writing your own method and attaching it using [`after_update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: OK, I think I am slowly getting the idea. So you would use a virtual attribute in the form then? As suggested by Marek?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32280/discussion-between-mike-campbell-and-tintin81)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "virtual" attribute, called - let's say - `email_input` and show field for this attribute (instead of `email`) in view:

```
<%= f.text_field :email_input %>
```

Then in your model you should have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :email_input
  attr_accessible :email_input
  before_save :set_email, :if => lambda{|p| p.email_input.present?}

  # ...
  def set_email
    email_input.downcase!
    if new_record?
      self.email = email_input
    else
      self.new_email = email_input
      send_email_confirmation_link
    end
  end
end
```